# How to set each value of an xts object to the minimum of all previous values?

Tags: r, xts

This does what I want, but I don't think it's the right way to do it...

```
for (n in 1:length(z)) {
     if (z[n,] > min(z[1:n,]) ) {
         z[n,] = min(z[1:n,])
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `cummin`?

```
set.seed(1)
z <- sample(1:10)
z
# [1]  3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6 10  1

cummin(z)
# [1] 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 1
```